# Вызов класса в методе этого класса. Наследование в C#

Tags: c#, наследование

Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне реализовать данную логику (что написать вместо 'ТУТ')

```
public class EagerBuyer : Buyer
{
    public EagerBuyer(Card card, double budget) : base(card, budget)
    {

    }
    public override void VisitStores(List<Store> stores)
    {       
        i.SellProduct(j.Product, j.Count, ТУТ);                 
    }
```

Где i - объект типа Product, j - количество данного продукта

```
public class Store{    
    public void SellProduct(Product product, int count, Buyer buyer)
    {
    }
}



public abstract class Buyer
{
    protected Card card;
    protected double budget;
    protected List<Wish> wishList;
    protected List<Product> hasBought;

    protected Buyer(Card card, double budget)
    {
        this.card = card;
        this.budget = budget;
        this.wishList = new List<Wish>();
        this.hasBought = new List<Product>();
    }
    public abstract void VisitStores(List<Store> stores);
}
```

И получается мне нужно передать самого EagerBuyer в метод который он имеет

Comment: Может быть `this`

Comment: Какую именно?  ?

Comment: спасибо все решил